# Connecting MySQL with downloaded sample database

Tags: mysql, database

I've downloaded sample database, which is currently in my Downloads folder. How to connect it with MySQL console so I could test some queries?

Every tutorial I've seen so far is about how to make your own database and then test queries.

Comment: What kind of file did you download?

Comment: Downloaded what from where to what environment?

Comment: Zipped .sql file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the "employees" sample?

That is a (zipped) SQL file, which you can load into MySQL by running

```
mysql < employees.sql
```

After unzipping. Eventully you also have to provide `-u root` as username and `-p` so it asks for a password.

If you use a GUI like MySQL WorkBench it has a menu entry to import SQL scripts.

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html and
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html